# Директории в локальной сети Python

Tags: python

У меня на Windows 10 в Network есть компьютер, и я хочу туда отправить файл. Директория в проводнике к нему `\\\DESKTOP-RD8QMC8`, но если в Python прописываешь `open('\\\DESKTOP-RD8QMC8')`, то пишет `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Можно ли как-то задать директорию к этому ПК, или нужно действовать как-то иначе? Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Это имя ПК туда писать и не получится.. на этом компе надо расшарить общую папку и уже в нее можно будет писать данные.

Comment: Предлагаю смонтиповать сетевую папку как диск. Это делается и через cmd и через GUI, так что у вас есть выбор=)